# Vector Analysis: Why are the Grad, Laplacian and Div being evaluated to zero

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, differential-equations, vector-calculus

For the non linear partial differential equation below, why are the Gradient, Laplacian and Divergence being evaluated to zero despite using the `VectorAnalysis` package.

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
Bo = 1/300;
\[Delta] = 10^-3;
\[Epsilon] = 10^-6;
r = 0;
m = 0.05;
\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(h[x, y, t]\)\) + 
 Div[-h[x, y, t]^3 Bo Grad[h[x, y, t]] + 
   h[x, y, t]^3 Grad[
     Laplacian[h[x, y, t]]] + ((\[Delta] h[x, y, t]^3) Grad[
     h[x, y, t]])/(Bi h[x, y, t] + K1)^3 + 
   m (h[x, y, t]/(K1 + Bi h[x, y, t]))^2 Grad[
     h[x, y, t]]] + \[Epsilon]/(Bi h[x, y, t] + K1) + r \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\((
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]
\*FractionBox[
SuperscriptBox[\(h[x, y, t]\), \(2\)], \(K1 + Bi\ h[x, y, t]\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(h[x, y, t]\), \(3\)])\)\)
```

I am doing this because I'd like to evaluate the magnitude of each of these terms at a certain time step.

Here is a simple sample code **without the Vector Analysis package** that works fine:

I solve a PDE using NDSolve and then plot each term (I call each of the two terms Eq1 and Eq2 here) at a certain time step.

```
sol = u /. 
  NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
      0.5 D[u[t, x], x, x] + u[t, x] D[u[t, x], x],  
     u[t, -Pi] == u[t, Pi] == 0 , u[0, x] == Sin[x]}, 
    u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -Pi, Pi}][[1]];

Eq1 = 0.5 D[u[t, x], x, x];
Magnitude1[t_, x_] = Eq1 /. u -> sol
Plot[Magnitude1[1.5, x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

```
Eq2 = u[t, x] D[u[t, x], x];
Magnitude2[t_, x_] = Eq2 /. u -> sol
Plot[Magnitude2[1.5, x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you do SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x,y,z]]? It does the trick for me :-)

Comment: @chris Boy, do I feel like an idiot. Should I delete this question?

Comment: may be you should check if its already been asked. otherwise its useful idiocy ;-)

Comment: @chris I checked. This hasn't been asked before. If you feel it's useful idiocy, I'll let it be. I am thinking however, I should receive negative points for dumb-itude such as this.

Comment: Interestingly, 6 of the 8 posts involving SetCoordinates were asked by you...  :-)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Either I need to get my head checked or Mathematica although has fantastic depth and breadth is rather unintuitive  to me since I need to get my head checked (tautology?)... `:P`

Comment: @DrN well to be fair one could imagine that the default of grad etc. could be `Cartesian[x,y,z]`. It wouldn't hurt!

Comment: @chris Yes, you are right. However, It would be kinda irregular to ask Mathematica to "DO ME A GRAD!" without specifying the coordinate system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operators like `Div` require the specifications of a coordinate system. By default, this coordinate system is cartesian and in terms of variables `Xx`, `Yy` and `Zz`. If you specify the vector field in terms of `x`, `y` and `z`, its derivatives with respect to the coordinates will be zero and the `Div` operator will correctly evaluate to zero.

The coordinate system can be changed manually. The following code will yield 3 as intended.

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x,y,z]];
Div[{x,y,z}]
```

Comment: "By default" would suggest that I don't need to specify `SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x,y,z]];
`, but I had to.

Comment: You don't need to. Div[{Xx,Yy,Zz}] will work without changing the coordinate system.

Comment: @MarckThomas but it didn't. I had to specify a cartesian coordinate system before I tried a Div or Grad ...

Comment: Interesting. The VectorAnalysis reference reads: "The initial default coordinate system is Cartesian, with coordinate variables Xx, Yy, and Zz." What does your Coordinates[] initially give?

Comment: After loading `VectorAnalysis`,  `Coordinates[]` gives me an error message: Coordinates::shdw: Symbol Coordinates appears in multiple contexts {VectorAnalysis`,Global`}; definitions in context VectorAnalysis` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >>

Comment: @drN It seems you have a local conflict. Try restarting with a new session. On MMA 8.0.4 `Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]; `Div[{Xx, Yy, Zz}]` returns 3.